# Python read Router IP from file and telnet into

Tags: python, telnet, readline

I would like to read a router IP from a text file, then telnet into it:

```
import sys
import telnetlib

f = open("C:\\MyIP.txt","r")
line = f.readline()

user = "username"
password = "password"

for line in f:

  tn = telnetlib.Telnet(line)
  tn.read_until("Login: ")
  tn.write(user + "\n")
  if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

f.close()
```

However, in the above code, if I try to read it directly from a file, it's not working.

Only like this:

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib
hostserver = "192.168.2.1"
newline = "\n"
username = "username" + newline
password = "password" + newline
telnet = telnetlib.Telnet(hostserver)
telnet.read_until("Login: ")
telnet.write(username+ "\n")
telnet.read_until("Password: ")
telnet.write(password+ "\n")
while 1:
    command = raw_input("> ")
    telnet.write(command+ "\n")
    if command == "exit":
        break
    telnet.read_all()
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: How is it not working? What is the rror?

Answer (score 1):

You have the statement

```
line = f.readline()
```

and then later, you have:

```
for line in f:
```

The `for` loop will loop over each line of the file *that has not already been read*. It doesn't really look like you want to loop at all. Remove the `for` statement since your `line` variable has already been set above.